# WebGl rendering is very slow with JSON file, is it because of size of JSON file?

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I am trying to render a very complex model using json file. The size of the json file is 40MB it is a huge data, I can render the model on canvas.

Now the problem is rendering is done very very slowly. If i try to rotate the model or zoom in, whole browser hangs, it is such a slow.

As i m new to webgl i do not know what is causing this problem. Looked around didnt find anything.

Is it the size of json file which is affecting rendering? how can i make the perfomance better? I should mention this, it is not a problem of graphic card. things like body browser is very fast.

I am using three.js jason loader for this method

```
loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( 'file.js', function ( geometry ) {
    geometry.computeVertexNormals();
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( ) );
    scene.add( mesh );
} );
```

For rendering, i am doing this inside init

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Render function is called in animate()

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    stats.update();
}
```

and in render function rotating the mesh like this

```
function render() {
    mesh.rotation.x += ( targetXRotation - mesh.rotation.x ) * 0.05;
    mesh.rotation.y += ( targetYRotation - mesh.rotation.y ) * 0.05;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Comment: It is very likely because of the IO.  The IO delay to read a 40MB file would be high enough to cause slow rendering.  Also, it's JSON, not jason.

Comment: Could you please show us some code, especially the rendering method? Are you using a buffer for your data?

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply, in that case what is an efficient process to load json file? Even body browser is a huge data, what is the principle behind it? Thanx @Corbin for Json correction(effect of sleepless work).

Comment: @Matthias I am not using buffer. I am using three.js renderer to render the model.

Comment: This is just a hack and not an answer. Try reducing the polygon count of the model. Blender has an option called decimate which does it. Most 3D models in my experience have too much detail for your average webapp.

Comment: @Sharun thanx for the idea. I do not know weather doing decimate will cause any trouble, but thanx for the idea though. i will read a little about it and try doing it...will let u know if it is working.

Comment: @Sharun it is a non manifold mesh so decimate is not working. Up for a great idea though, can implement next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this question as "webgl", so I think you would like to use the **WebGL** renderer:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
```

instead of the **canvas** one:

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

Answer (score 2):

It could depend on the structure of your 40meg file. How many individual models are there? The more models the slower it will go.

What do I mean by models?

Well, if you go into your favorite modeling package and make 2 spheres you have 2 models. If you make 1000 spheres, let's say 1000 polygons each and export it will likely run slow. But if you find out how to collapse those 1000 spheres models into a single model of 1000 spheres and export again it will likely run fast.

Drawing 1 big thing is often faster than drawing 1000 small things.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think i was rendering it on canvas space was a problem, now it takes time only to load after loading it works fine. I have ticked right for Juan Mellado, it solved my problem. @gman Thanks for the modelling suggestion, i will always keep in mind this trick, before implementing next thing.   Actually it is a single model which is converted from .stl to .obj and then to .js. So i would say single model made up of lot many polygon, it is a model of skull. If i have understood ur concept wrong, any piece of suggestion is welcome. up for the help.

Comment: hey gman, how does this work when you have more than 2^16 faces performance wise? Should you manually break the geometry and manage the draw calls, or let whatever is taking care of it, take care of it?

Comment: Perf relative to what? If you need to draw > 2^16 vertices you have 2 options. Multiple draw calls or non-indexed geometry. Non-indexed geometry is not limited to 2^16 vertices on WebGL. I don't know which is faster. It might depend on how [optimized the indices and vertices are](https://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/papers/fast_vert_cache_opt.html). Mostly I wouldn't worry about it. I'd make tools that auto-split my models and then forget about it.